# Scala factory pattern returns unusable abstract type

Tags: scala, factory-method

Please let me know how to make the following bit of code work as intended.  The problem is that the Scala compiler doesn't understand that my factory is returning a concrete class, so my object can't be used later.  Can TypeTags or type parameters help?  Or do I need to refactor the code some other way?  I'm (obviously) new to Scala.

```
trait Animal
trait DomesticatedAnimal extends Animal
trait Pet extends DomesticatedAnimal {var name: String = _}
class Wolf extends Animal
class Cow extends DomesticatedAnimal
class Dog extends Pet

object Animal {
    def apply(aType: String) = {
        aType match {
            case "wolf" => new Wolf
            case "cow" => new Cow
            case "dog" => new Dog
        }
    }
}

def name(a: Pet, name: String) {
  a.name = name
  println(a +"'s name is: " + a.name)
}                                               

val d = Animal("dog")                                                     
name(d, "fred")
```

The last line of code fails because the compiler thinks `d` is an `Animal`, not a `Dog`.

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to infer that `d` is a `Dog`?

Comment: @giorgio, that's what I'm trying to understand. I see the problem but I don't know how to solve it except for adding more code for each class.

Comment: `d` cannot be of type `Pet` (as required by function `name()`) because `Animal.apply()` returns an `Animal` and not all animals are `Pet`'s. E.g., `Wolf` is not a `Pet`. So the compiler is right to complain about your types: `d` could have type `Pet` if **all** the possible results of `Animal.apply()` were of type `Pet`.

Comment: Thanks @giorgio, I'm now very clear on what the problem is. What I'm searching for is guidance on how to avoid the problem.

Comment: Maybe you could define an object `Pet` whose apply method only creates pets: cats, dogs, and so on. Annotating the return type explicitly should give you extra guidance: `def apply(aType: String): Pet = ...`.

Answer (score 4):

You should create companion objects with `apply` method for each subclass of `Animal` instaed of `Animal` trait. Also, it is considered a bad practice to use mutable field like you did with `name`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, without changing anything else :

```
val d = Animal("dog").asInstanceOf[Dog]     //> d  : Test.Dog = Test$$anonfun$main$1$Dog$1@1030dda
name(d, "fred")                                   //> Test$$anonfun$main$1$Dog$1@1030dda's name is: fred
```

But, i don't think it's a very good idea...

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to sound rude but the compiler is right about assuming that `d` is an `Animal` because that's what the `Animal.apply` method returns.

As already pointed out you could force the type of d with an explicit cast but it simply wouldn't be type safe. It would be leveraging your knowledge about the method implementation as a programmer, which will eventually become a source of bugs as your codebase grows and you possibly change previous code in unexpected ways.

If you need to call a `Pet` method then you would better use a factory method that creates `Pet` objects, or at least check the object type before doing the type cast, using

```
if (d.isInstanceOf[Pet]) name(d.asInstanceOf[Pet], "Fred")
```

Or better still, using pattern matching

```
val d = Animal("dog")
d match {
  case p: Pet => name(p, "fred")
  case _ =>
}
```